# OPENgl - GL/glut.h no such file or directory

Tags: c++, opengl

can any one help me with the following error

GL/glut.h no such file or directory

The things I did are

1. After installation of MinGW i have added the Path to the path
   enviornment variable
2. Added 'glut.h' to C:\MinGW\Include\GL
3. Added glut32.dll to C:\Windows\SysWOW64
4. Added glut32.lib to the project folder
5. COmpiled with 'g++ -o hello.exe -Wall hello.c glee.lib glut32.lib -lopengl32 -lglu32'

and still the error above persist please help

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<iostream>
//#include<conio.h>

void render(void);

void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y);

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char** atgv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
glutCreateWindow("Sample GLUT Application");

glutDisplayFunc(render);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);

glutMainLoop();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y)
{
if(c == 27){
    exit(0);
    }
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON )
{
    exit(0);
}
}

void render(void)
{   
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);  
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.5);
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

some simple things that can cause problems in my experience (so make sure they are set!:) :

- check to see if `C:\MinGW\bin` is in your path variable if not, add `C:\MinGW\bin` to your PATH (type %path% in a console window to ensure the path property is applied to the window console session you are using)
- put `glut32.dll` into `C:\windows\system32` so it can be located at runtime, or place it in the same directory as the executable you wish to run
- Just checked and my minGW has `glut32.dll` in `c:\mingw\bin`
- and `libglut32.a` in `c:\mingw\lib`
- and `glut.h` should be in `c:\mingw\include\GL`

Apologies for the previous omission.

That should see you alright provided there are no other issues at play.

Let me know if you need more info/help :)

**Addendum:**

I located [this link](http://www.prinmath.com/csci5229/misc/install.html)  which whilst old may be of use to you in making the files available to mingw's environment.

Comment: same result sir what ever said has be precisely done

Comment: done the changes same result sir. Where can I go wrong SHd i add the code?

Comment: Include done in my code
#include<GL\glut.h>
#include<iostream>

Comment: yes please if you can include the code that may help as well, call me Gianni by the way, sir seems awfully formal;)

Comment: Sir thank you very much for the link. But I have referred to it.

Answer (score 2):

**On a Debian based systems such as Ubuntu, do**

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm on a debian based system and it's still not working :/.

Comment: @DzDev this one: `sudo apt install freeglut3-dev`

Answer (score 0):

On ArchLinux,
installing freeglut worked for me

```
sudo pacman -S freeglut
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `#include<GL/glut.h>`

Use `#include "GL/glut.h"`