# Call of cl.exe to compile opengl c++ code

Tags: c#, c++, opengl

I have an app in c# and I want to compile with cl.exe an opengl - cpp file. When I try to compile I always get the error **GL/GLUT.h: No such file or directory**. I tried to put both gl.h and glut.h in the same folder as the cpp file but nothing. Also, before `#include <GL/GLUT.h>`, is `#include <GL/GL.h>`, but this is ok...it shouldn't give me an error for gl.h first? Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858072/opengl-gl-glut-h-no-such-file-or-directory) and see if it has your answer

Comment: I don't use MinGW. I use Visual Studio. Though I followed some of the steps (put the glut32.dll in c:/windows/system32) and now I get the same error for gl.h...I'm driving crazy..I put the dll and in my current folder...the same again..

Comment: Where exactly is the GLUT.h file?

Comment: I put it in the same folder as my cpp file

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting them in same folder then you have to write your include statement like this

> #include "glut.h"

You dont need to include gl.h as glut will do that for you.

Comment: I did this and it worked! But now I get a linker error. It cannot open glut32.lib, which is also in my current folder.

Comment: you need to link glut32.lib in project properties linker options or write `#pragma "glut32.lib"` in your main.cpp for a quick and dirty solution

Comment: try this `#pragma comment(lib,"glut32.lib")`

Comment: In drop that ".lib" and try.
`#pragma comment(lib,"glut32")`